# Convex conjugate of composition with non-invertible linear transform

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

I want to compute the convex conjugate $f^*$ of $f(x)=\lVert Ax \rVert$, where $x\in \mathbb R^n$ and $A\in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$ such that $\mbox{ran}(A)=\mathbb{R}^m$. Here

$$ f^*(x^*)=\sup_{x\in \mathbb R^n}\{(x^*)^Tx-\lVert Ax \rVert\}$$

I know that $\mathbb R^n=\ker(A)+\ker(A)^{\perp}$, and $A|_{\ker(A)^{\perp}}$ it is invertible, so if $x\in \ker(A)^{\perp}$ here is easy to compute $f^*(x^*)$, but I don't know how to use this fact in my problem and how (if it is posible) to vanish supremum over all $\mathbb{R}^n$ and instead of  that calculate convex conjugate over $\ker(A)^{\perp}$. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proposition 13.24 from Bauschke & Combettes' book (volume 2) states that the Legendre ("convex") conjugate of $g\circ A$ is written

$$f^* = (g\circ A)^* = A^* \triangleright g^*$$
where $A^*$ is its adjoint (so since it's real you can just use the transpose) and $\triangleright$ is the *infimal postcomposition*:

$$(\forall y\in\mathbb{R}^m)\quad A^*\triangleright g^*(y)=\inf_{\substack{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\\A^*x=y}}g^*(x).\tag{*}$$

Example 14.5 (same book) states that 
$$g^*(x)=(\|\cdot\|^*)(x)=\iota_{B(0;1)}(x) = \begin{cases}
+\infty &\text{if}\;\;\|x\|>1\\
0 &\text{if}\;\; \|x\|\leq 1
\end{cases}.$$
Here I use $\iota_C$ to denote the $0$-$\infty$ indicator function and $B(0;1)$ denotes the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
If $B(0;1)$ intersected with the inverse image $(A^*)^{-1}y$ is nonempty, then the infimum in (*) ought to occur when $g^*=0$ i.e. $x\in B(0;1)$. Otherwise, it is identically $+\infty$. Altogether,

$$(\forall y\in \mathbb{R}^m)\quad f^*(y)=\begin{cases}
0 &\text{if}\;\;A^{-1}y\cap B(0;1)\neq \varnothing\\
+\infty &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.$$

Again, $A^{-1}y=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\, |\, Ax=y\}$ is always a well-defined set so here we do not require $A$ to be invertible.

Comment: I am, how do I say, not convinced. We might have different editions, 13.24 is about p-norms specifically, for me. Further, you might mean proposition 13.21 (v), stating: $(f \circ L)^* \leq L^* \triangleright f^*$. Note the less-or-equal, rather than equality, which I can't seem to find - and I even think is false.

Comment: Not saying that the answer as a whole is wrong, since OP stated that $\mbox{ran}(A) = \mathbb R^m$ the equality is true in his case, but the argument for that is missing from your answer.

Comment: @WorldSEnder good points, although equality holds as long as $L^*\triangleright g^*$ is proper, convex, and lower semicontinuous. This follows from the facts that (1) functions in this class are equal to their biconjugate and (2) conjugation reverses inequality. So, for this particular case, we are alright (e.g. one sufficient condition is that $-\infty$ is not in the range, demonstrated in Corollary 13.25) And yeah, I'm using volume 2 which has Prop 13.24 with this result. Thanks for pointing out this hole in the original argument.